# How to start redis-server and a node.js app on the same container?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

As the title, I tried the Dockerfile something as below.

```
# install redis-server and start it
RUN yum install -y redis
RUN service redis start

# run node app when container starts
CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

In app.js, I connect to redis with localhost

But when I tried to run the container, it turned out the redis-server was not running on localhost and the app.js failed to start.

I know usually people start redis and node.js app in separate containers, but why cannot I do this?

Please give me some opinions about this.

Answer (score 4):

In a container, you usually start only one software. You can start more than one, but you need some tools like supervisor https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/ runit, s6, daemontools, see the FAQ https://docs.docker.com/faq/

Answer (score 1):

you'd need something like supervisor, why not have 2 containers and use docker-compose?

recommended base image for your approach: https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker

Comment: I am just wondering why cannot I run 2 processes in a container.

Comment: can, as I said, with supervisor - but remember docker is not a VM. look up phusion passenger for proper init and supervisor containers (although I'm not for this approach at all).

Comment: now your container is responsible for ensuring the services run and your orchestration tools can't. Having 1 service per container allows full separation of concerns between containers and gives your orchestration tools container level management.